# react-native-table-component freeze first column & first row in scrollable table

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

**Desired State**

I'm using react-native-table-component, a basic component to render tables in React Native.  I need to freeze the first column and first row in the table so they remain in view when scrolling.  Specifically, I need the first column to remain fixed when scrolling horizontally and scroll with the rest of the data in the row when scrolling vertically.

I need the first row to function the same way.  Remain fixed when scrolling vertically and when scrolling horizontally, I should scroll with the corresponding column.

**Issue**

I can get to my desired state for the first row but I can't do the same for the first column in the same table.

**Code**

```
render(){
    return(

    <View style={styles.tableContainer}>
    <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
     <View>
       <Table style={styles.tableHead}>

         <Row
          style={styles.header}
          textStyle={styles.text}
          data={this.props.tableHead}
          widthArr={this.props.columnWidth}
        />

       </Table>
       <ScrollView style={styles.dataWrapper}>

        <TableWrapper style={styles.tableBody}>
          <Col 
            style={styles.title} 
            textStyle={styles.text}
            data={this.props.tableTitle} 
            heightArr={[28,28]}  
        />
          <Rows 
            style={styles.row} 
            textStyle={styles.text}
            data={this.dataFormat()} 
            widthArr={this.props.columnWidth} 

            />
        </TableWrapper>
       </ScrollView>
     </View>
   </ScrollView>
  </View>
    )
}
```

**Additional Information**
I don't need to use react-native-table-component but I'd like to if possible since I've already done a lot of work to style it and format the data I've inserted.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: this is precisely my issue, any chance you came up with a solution?

Comment: No I haven’t yet!  I put it off for now but I’ll definitely need to solve it in the next couple months.  I had read online about using two scroll views, one for the left column that you want fixed and another for the rest of the table.  You then “link” the two together so when one is scrolled, the other one scrolls too.  I haven’t tried this yet but it may be the only option

Comment: have you tried this: https://build.affinity.co/building-a-highly-responsive-sheet-view-with-react-native-51129ec34c63 (they have a snack example as well in the article). It involves a listview and a flatlist (along with an animation to make the scrolling look smooth), I'm gonna try it today and report back.

Comment: I suggest trying to fit your table into the template I showed above, it worked like a charm (even in my case with 9 columns and 170+ rows)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working solution. Basically, you need to sync the vertical scroll on the left pane with the first column pane.

```
// TableDemo.tsx

import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import {
  Table,
  Row,
  Rows,
  Col,
} from 'react-native-table-component';

const borderColor = '#C1C0B9';
const primaryColor = 'dodgerblue';
const backgroundColor = '#F7F6E7';

export default function TableDemo() {
  const leftRef = useRef<ScrollView>(null);
  const rightRef = useRef<ScrollView>(null);

  const state = {
    tableHead: [
      'Head1',
      'Head2',
      'Head3',
      'Head4',
      'Head5',
      'Head6',
      'Head7',
      'Head8',
      'Head9',
    ],
    widthArr: [50, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200],
  };

  const headerHeight = 40;
  const leftColumnWidth = 100;

  const recordData = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 60; i += 1) {
    const rowData = [];
    rowData.push(`Record ${i}`);
    recordData.push(rowData);
  }

  const tableData = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 60; i += 1) {
    const rowData = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < 9; j += 1) {
      rowData.push(`${i}${j}`);
    }
    tableData.push(rowData);
  }

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: '#eee',
      }}
    >
      {/* Left Column */}
      <View
        style={{
          width: leftColumnWidth,
          backgroundColor: 'yellow',
          borderRightWidth: 1,
          borderRightColor: borderColor,
        }}
      >
        {/* Blank Cell */}
        <View
          style={{
            height: headerHeight,
            backgroundColor: primaryColor,
            borderBottomWidth: 1,
            borderBottomColor: borderColor,
          }}
        ></View>
        {/* Left Container : scroll synced */}
        <ScrollView
          ref={leftRef}
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'white',
          }}
          scrollEnabled={false}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        >
          <Table
            borderStyle={{
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderColor,
            }}
          >
            {recordData.map((rowData, index) => (
              <Row
                key={index}
                data={rowData}
                widthArr={[leftColumnWidth]}
                style={index % 2 ? styles.row : { backgroundColor }}
                textStyle={styles.text}
              />
            ))}
          </Table>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
      {/* Right Column */}
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: 'white',
        }}
      >
        <ScrollView horizontal={true} bounces={false}>
          <View>
            <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor }}>
              <Row
                data={state.tableHead}
                widthArr={state.widthArr}
                style={styles.head}
                textStyle={{ ...styles.text, color: 'white' }}
              />
            </Table>
            <ScrollView
              ref={rightRef}
              style={styles.dataWrapper}
              scrollEventThrottle={16}
              bounces={false}
              onScroll={(e) => {
                const { y } = e.nativeEvent.contentOffset;
                leftRef.current?.scrollTo({ y, animated: false });
              }}
            >
              <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor }}>
                {tableData.map((rowData, index) => (
                  <Row
                    key={index}
                    data={rowData}
                    widthArr={state.widthArr}
                    style={index % 2 ? styles.row : { backgroundColor }}
                    textStyle={styles.text}
                  />
                ))}
              </Table>
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, padding: 16, paddingTop: 30, backgroundColor: '#eee' },
  head: { height: 40, backgroundColor: primaryColor },
  wrapper: { flexDirection: 'row' },
  title: { flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#f6f8fa' },
  row: { height: 28 },
  text: { textAlign: 'center' },
  dataWrapper: { marginTop: -1 },
});
```